# How to check logs in running server on docker

Tags: docker, api, npm

I developed apps and run them on the docker.

I'd like to see logs during the development.

I can see them by `docker logs api-server`.

But now I must send this command every time for debut.

So I decided to enter container by following command.

`docker exec -it api-server sh`

And then I want to watch logs real timely.

Are there any method to watch realtime logs on server(for example access log)  ?

`Dockerfile` of `api-server` is following

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /src
COPY package.json .

RUN rm -rf /src/node_modules
RUN rm -rf /src/package-lock.json
RUN apk --no-cache add curl



RUN yarn install

CMD yarn start:debug
```

`package.json` is following

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing `docker exec`, I'm assuming you're either running `api-server` in `detached` mode or you're accessing this container from another place (other window or pc) to do `docker exec`.

If you want an "access.log" type of behavior, you can certainly write your `docker logs api-server` to a file.

Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48345336
The `-f` flag will continue writing to this file everytime `api-server` spits out a new stdout/stderr, so you don't need to keep doing `docker logs api-server`.

On a side note, for complicated logging and workflows for containers, (especially container resource statistics), I use the [Docker SDK](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html), where you can use `container.logs(stdout=True)` and write this to a file, so that everything will be captured without you doing anything.

Alternatively, you can create a script that writes the stdout/stderr to a docker volume shared between some network drive or host machine, and in your `Dockerfile`, just copy this script over to your `$HOME/.profile` (or `.bashrc` depending on your shell).

Comment: Thanks As I am begineer, I'd like to know where must I write `docker logs api-server` ? I tried`docker-compose up` and `docker logs -f api-server` but they didn't omit access log.As I developed `API` it was big issue.. Thanks